# How to put a double-sided B5 document on A4 paper for duplex printing?

Tags: double-sided, classicthesis, printing

I have a ClassicThesis B5 document:

```
\documentclass[
b5paper,
twoside,
openright,
titlepage,
numbers=noenddot,
headinclude,
footinclude,
cleardoublepage=empty,
BCOR=5mm,
fontsize=10pt,
abstract=on,
]{scrreprt}
```

I want to duplex-print it on the standard A4 paper and then crop.
How do I place pages on A4 in such a way?
Both `geometry` and `crop` fail to produce right paper size, put crop marks in correct places or just mess up with margins and layout.

Maybe, `pdfpages` can "print" to the corner of A4 and add crop marks?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example code that reproduces the problem. As it stands, it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print double-sided B5 on two sides of A4 for later cropping I used `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale=true,frame,
% offset is half the difference between A4 and B5
offset=-17mm 23.5mm]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```